# SQL Server Report Builder - How to aggregate rows of a group

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, reporting

I am creating a report and have an issue to concatenate strings within a group. E.g. I have the following structure of a table

```
NameOfPerson | Country | State
```

I grouped the table by *NameofPerson* and the sub group *Country*.

```
-Name
--Country
```

Now, if I expand *Country* I get a list of all *States* but I would like to have on the sub group lvl of *Country* a concatination of States.

E.g.

```
-Name:Bill
--Country: America | State: Virgina, Texas, California
--Country: Canada| State: Alberta, Ontario
```

How can I do this?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: You'd probably be better off having your SQL query do the concatenation (use COALESCE), and then you can just display the result in the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **LookUpSet** to look up the states and **JOIN** to combine them into a string.

```
=JOIN(LOOKUPSET(Fields!Country.Value, Fields!Country.Value, Fields!State.Value, "DataSet1"),", ")
```

Depending on your data this may have duplicates. You may want to create a separate dataset of the countries and states.